# how to resize x and y axis

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

How can I resize x and y axis ?

What I want, n more specific;

```
3900  |
  .   |
  .   |
  .   |
  60  |
      |
  30  |
      |_____________________________
      0  60  120  180  ...        3600
```

What I have done ;

```
  a = [0:0.1:10000];
  plot(a);
```

What should I write so that resizing x and y axis is done as expected?

EDIT:

I do not want;

```
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
3900  |
  .   |
  .   |
  .   |
  60  |
      |
  30  |
      |___________________________________________________________________
      0  60  120  180  ...        3600
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean resize?  Do you want to keep the same scale, but change the size of the whole plot?  Or do you actually want to zoom into a particular data range in the plot?

Comment: @Xurtio look my question again

Comment: I agree the previous-in-code use of xlim... and axis... commands do not keep the figure from resetting with scatter3... , but xlim ... and axis .. commands AFTER scatter... does reset figure to the desired limits. Perhaps this was the original intent of the previous answers.

Answer (score 7):

Check the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axis.html

```
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

Comment: From the documentation: "XTick, YTick, ZTick
vector of data values locating tick marks

Tick spacing. A vector of x-, y-, or z-data values that determine the location of tick marks along the respective axis. If you do not want tick marks displayed, set the respective property to the empty vector, [ ]. These vectors must contain monotonically increasing values." If you are getting errors post all your code and the error

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
xlim([0 3600])
ylim([0 3900])
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlim.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ylim.html

I think for the step size it's

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [0:60:3600])
set(gca, 'YTick', [0:30:3900])
```

Comment: "axes ( 'XTick' ... " gives error : implicit conversion from matrix to string. And, it emits " line 800020: all points y value undefined!"

Comment: @user1414276 Weird. Try breaking it up onto two statements. If that doesn't work then I don't know.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `set(gca, 'XTick', [0:1:1000])`?

Comment: Your advice is not work. Can you write these code to your octave? Figure is so ridiculus .

Comment: @Li-aungYip your advice also not work. Can you please write my code wth your advice to your terminal in order to understand why it not works.

Comment: @Li-aungYip can you look my question again ?

Comment: The above probably all works in MATLAB. If you're using Octave, you need to actually specify that. (Applying both the `octave` *and* `MATLAB` tags confused me as to which you were actually using.)